# How two person can work on same project using GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have a git hub account i created one project and push it to my online git hub repository
after than one of my friend login with his git hub account and fork my repository.After he modified that project he want to push that project. For that what i did is i added his SSH key to my git hub account but when he push the project it going to his git account how do i get code whatever he has modified or added new code . I am very new to version controlling. can anyone help me how do we two or more people can work on same project.

Comment: IMPORTANT: Do *not* add somebody else's SSH key to your account! This allows them to authenticate as you!

Answer (score 4):

There is an option called add collaborator in settings
add your friend name in that field so that he will be added to the project

```
-> Go to your project 

-> Click on admin

-> Add Collaborator

-> Add your friend
```

Comment: If i will add my friend as collaborator than after than what he has to do i mean he has to clone my project or fork. Sorry if my question is silly because i never work on version controlling

Comment: He has to clone the repo to his local machine, just like you do. But he doesn't have to fork the repo on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Akhilraj regarding just adding your friend as a collaborator.

Forking is more for somebody external to your project who wants to work on it, and then send you pull requests so you can pull his changes from the fork into your original repository. Since this guy is your friend, my guess is that you want to work more directly with him, so I would say don't mess around with a fork.

**IMPORTANT:** Do **not** add your friend's SSH key to your account! The SSH key is for authentication (i.e. proving you are who you say you are), not for authorization (i.e., giving access to a repo). By adding your friend's SSH key to your account, you're making it possible for him to authenticate as you. In effect you are telling GitHub that anybody with the private half of that key pair is you.